# Adding New Row In Reduced Screen Sizes Does Not Perceive Media Queries Class Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

A section of my form is a row of data that is formatted responsively with media queries. The user may add additional rows. This is done using JavaScript (jQuery). The problem is, when I clone the new row, not all changed formatting, as laid out in media queries, is read, instead, reverting to the formatting in the original stylesheet.

**Row (HTML with some PHP)**

```
    <div class="WFormSection BOLItems">
    <div class="WTableHead">
        <div class="alignleft FormCol60 WHeadText">Units</div>
        <div class="space"></div>
        <div class="alignleft FormCol20 WHeadText">Haz</div>
        <div class="space"></div>
        <div class="alignleft FormColMid WHeadText">Description of Articles</div>
        <div class="space"></div>
        <div class="alignleft FormCol60 WHeadText">NMFC</div>
        <div class="space"></div>
        <div class="alignleft FormCol60 WHeadText">Class</div>
        <div class="space"></div>
        <div class="alignleft FormColTiny WHeadText">Weight</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!--=============================== -->
    <!--           R O W  0             -->
    <!--=============================== -->
    <div class="parent-group">
        <div class="form-group">
            <hr>
            <div class="alignleft FormCol60 TD Inline">
                <div class="ColTitle">Units: </div>
                <input type="text" id="Pieces(0)" name="Pieces[0]" maxlength="5" size="4" value="<?PHP echo($Pieces[0]); ?>" class="inputtext right FirstCell" placeholder="Units">
            </div>
            <div class="space"></div>
            <div class="alignleft FormCol20 Center TD Inline">
                <div class="ColTitle">Hazmat: </div>
                <label class="CBContainer CB">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="HM(0)" name="HM[0]" value="X" <?PHP if($HM[0]=="X"){echo('checked="Checked"');} ?>>
                    <span class="Checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="space"></div>
            <div class="ColTitle">Description:</div>
                <div class="alignleft FormColMid TD">
                    <div class="DescriptionTextarea">
                        <textarea class="txt" id="Descr(0)" name="Descr[0]" maxlength="53" placeholder="Description"><?PHP echo($Descr[0]); ?></textarea>
                        <input class="FormCol30 ChrCt" name="Output" id="Output" size="5" value="53" readonly disabled />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="space"></div>
            <div class="alignleft FormCol60 TD Inline">
                <div class="ColTitle">NMFC: </div>
                <input type="text" id="NMFC(0)" name="NMFC[0]" maxlength="10" size="8" value="<?PHP echo($NMFC[0]); ?>" class="inputtext right" placeholder="NMFC">
            </div>
            <div class="space"></div>
            <div class="alignleft FormCol60 TD Inline">
                <div class="ColTitle">Class: </div>
                <?PHP echo PopSelect('Class[0]', $ClassArr, $Class[0], 'DropBox2',1,0,'',0,'','','Class(0)'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="space"></div>
            <div class="alignleft FormColTiny TD Inline">
                <div class="ColTitle">Weight: </div>
                <input type="text" id="Weight(0)" name="Weight[0]" maxlength="5" size="4" value="<?PHP echo($Weight[0]); ?>" class="inputtext right EndCell" data-datarow=0 placeholder="Weight">
            </div>
            <div class="space"></div>
            <div class="alignleft form-group">
                <a class="RowDeleteButton del" id="DeleteRow" href="javascript:void(0)"> X </a>
            </div>
            <div class="Clear"></div>
        </div> <!-- child-group -->
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div> <!-- parent-group -->
```

What's happening here is that the original row is completely horizontal, thus the original column header (WHeadText). At smaller screen sizes, the header goes away, and the labels (ColTitle) come into play. So, at a certain screen size, the class "WHeadText" is hidden, and the class "ColTitle" appears. This works fine in the original row. In the cloned rows, neither the header, nor the labels appear, and other formatting is not changed, as well.

**JavaScript**

```
    <script>
    function CreateNewRow()
    {
        var ChildCount = $('.child-group').length;
        if(ChildCount == 7)
        {
            alert("Sorry, 8 is the maximum number of rows");
        }
        else
        {
            var len = window.LastArrayValue;
            window.LastArrayValue = len + 1;
            $('.parent-group').clone(true, true).find(':input').each(function(idx, ele)
            {
                var ename = ele.name;
                var eid   = ele.id
                var ArrayValue = len+1;
                ele.name = ename.replace(/(\[\/?[^\]]*\])/g, "["+ArrayValue+"]");
                ele.id   = eid.replace(/(\(\/?[^\]]*\))/g, "("+ArrayValue+")");
                if (typeof $(this).data('datarow') !== 'undefined'){$(this).data('datarow', ArrayValue);} // Skip if there is not a datarow attribute
                if(ele.type == "checkbox"){ele.checked = false;}
                else{ele.value = '';}
            }).end().find('.form-group').toggle(true).end()
              .toggleClass('parent-group child-group').hide()
              .appendTo('#container').slideDown('slow',function()
              {
                  $("#container").find(".FirstCell").last().focus();
              });
        }
    }
</script>
```

I can, of course, instigate the class changes with Javascript, but formatting changes more then once, and each time most of the formatting you see below changes, so that presents a real problem, in addition to the possible differences there may be detecting viewport by two different methods.

**CSS (Just for one example, here is one media query change):**

```
.WFormSection.BOLItems .ColTitle {display:block; padding-top:15px; width:75px; margin-right:15px; text-align:Left; clear:left; font-weight:bold;}
.WFormSection.BOLItems .CBContainer {margin-top:15px;}
.WFormSection.BOLItems .WTableHead {display:none;}
.WFormSection.BOLItems .TD {float:left;}
.WFormSection.BOLItems .DescriptionTextarea {margin-bottom:10px;}
.WFormSection.BOLItems .DescriptionTextarea textarea {width:80%;}
.BOLItems .FormColSmall, .BOLItems .FormColMedium, .BOLItems .FormColMid, .BOLItems .FormColWide {max-width:100%; padding-right:3px;}
```

**CSS From Original StyleSheet** (since it was requested):

```
.WFormSection {border:1px solid #969696; padding:15px; background:url(../images/comment-form_bg.png) 0 0 repeat-x #e9e9e9; margin-bottom:15px; position:relative;}
.WFormSectionTitle {color:#0F61AC; font-weight:500; font-size:16px; width:100%; text-align:center; margin-bottom:15px;}
.WFormSection .one_third {width:28%;}
.WFormSection .one_fourth {width:20%;}
.WFormSection .one_fifth {width:16.800%;}
.WFormSection .one_half {width:40%;}
.WFormSection .Split, .TrackBox .Split {float:left; width:48%; padding:0 1%;}
.WFormSection .CheckBox {width:100%;}
.WFormSection .StateDrop, .WFormSection .DateDrop, .WFormSection .SmallDrop, .WFormSection .LongDrop {padding:10px 10px 19px 10px; margin-top:4px;}
.WFormSection.SubnitBox {padding:8px; margin-top:20px; text-align:center;}
.WFormSection.SubmitBox .RadioHorizontal {display:inline-block; margin-left:20px;}
.WFormSection.Table {padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0;}
.WFormSection .VerticalSpace20 {height:20px;}
.WFormSection .form-group .DescriptionTextarea {height: 54px;}
.WFormSection .form-group .DescriptionTextarea textarea {width:85%; height:100%; line-height:110%;}
.WFormSection .form-group .DescriptionTextarea .ChrCt {display:inline-block; border:none; background:transparent; margin-left:10px; color:#D78E21; font-size:16px; font-weight:600;}
.WFormSection em {display:inline; padding-left:12px; font-style:normal;}
.WHeadText {color:#000000; display:block; font-weight:600}
.WHeadText {font-size:14px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:18px; width:100%; margin:3px 0; padding:7px 10px 7px 2px;}
.WFormSection .form-group .DescriptionTextarea {height: 54px;}
.WFormSection .form-group .DescriptionTextarea textarea {width:85%; height:100%; line-height:110%;}
.WFormSection .form-group .DescriptionTextarea .ChrCt {display:inline-block; border:none; background:transparent; margin-left:10px; color:#D78E21; font-size:16px; font-weight:600;}
.ColTitle {display:none;}
.CBContainer {display:block; position:relative; padding-left:24px; margin-bottom:8px; cursor:pointer; font-size:14px; -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; user-select:none;}
.CBContainer.RB {display:inline-block; padding-left:30px;}
/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.CBContainer input {position:absolute; opacity:0; cursor:pointer; height:0; width:0;}
/* Create a custom checkbox */
.CBContainer.CB .Checkmark {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; height:20px; width:20px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border:1px solid #585858;}
.CBContainer.RB .Checkmark {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; height:22px; width:22px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border:1px solid #585858; border-radius:50%;}
/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.CBContainer:hover input ~ .Checkmark {background-color:#CCCCCC;}
/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.CBContainer input:checked ~ .Checkmark {background-color:#2196F3;}
/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.CBContainer.CB .Checkmark:after, .CBContainer.RB .Checkmark:after {content:""; position:absolute; display:none;}
/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.CBContainer input:checked ~ .Checkmark:after {display:block;}
/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.CBContainer.CB .Checkmark:after {left:7px; top:3px; width:5px; height:12px; border:solid white; border-width:0 3px 3px 0; -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); -ms-transform:rotate(45deg); transform:rotate(45deg);}
.CBContainer.RB .Checkmark:after {left:6px; top:6px; width:8px; height:8px; border-radius:50%; background:#FFFFFF;}
.TD {} /* Not defined in original stylesheet */
.BOLItems {} /* Not defined in original stylesheet */
/* The other FormCol settings, as well as "Space" simply define the width and padding */
```

Comment: Where are your media-queries CSS ?

Comment: Under "CSS" The break points don't matter. There are more than one. I have given an example. I add the original CSS, if that will help.

Comment: @VVV Thanks. Turned out to be something quite stupid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was simply an extra closing div. It has been commented out.